# Child elements wrapping when animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to stop child elements from wrapping when animating. I want that they should stay as it is and not dance on the screen by wrapping. Here is my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39734/

This is my CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;

}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

Do you know how could I potentially fix this?

**Edit:** I don't want hacks by compulsorily aligning all content in my sidenav as `display:block`

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39738/

I want the UL to show up inline-block. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display block on your anchors should do it.

```
@media screen and (max-height: 450px)
(index):82
.sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
}
```

**Edit - following comments**

Further to the OP's requirements where the anchors should stay inline and not 'dance' I animated the position of the sidebar instead of the width.

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.left = "0";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.left = "-250px";
}
```

Comment: By not all my anchors would be display block. Do I have to compulsory add this and change my layout? or is there any other way?

Comment: I updated my question. Can you let me know if li inside ul will also need to be display block? because i want to show them inline-block

Comment: So if i understand correctly, you want the final position of the links to be 2 by 2?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39738/ is my updated fiddle. Can you see 4 lis? I want them to show up in the same line. Please do not do further hacks by removing lis and putting them in a single div :)

Comment: Excellent. Yours is the only correct answer. I went tired explaining it to gurvinder :) all answers would force me to change my layout. What is the main update that you did on it?

Comment: Instead of animating the width of the sidebar I animated the position so that the width can be kept at 250px. Thus, sliding the whole lot onto the viewport.

Comment: Super! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `display:block` to the `anchor`'s style

```
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display:block; //this is added
}
```

Or you can add it those which are direct descendants of `.sidenav`

```
.sidenav > a {
    display:block; //this is added
}
```

**Demo for `I don't want hack`**

```js
document.getElementById("open").onclick = openNav;

document.getElementById("close").onclick = closeNav;

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <ul>
    <li>I</li>
    <li>don't</li>
    <li>want</li>
    <li>hack</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" id="close" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span id="open" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer">&#9776; open</span>
```

**Edit**

Just add this line to your `ul`'s css

```
ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: By not all my anchors would be display block. Do I have to compulsory add this and change my layout? or is there any other way?

Comment: @TimLiberty Not all anchors, just the ones inside `.sidenav`

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. The ones inside sidenav.

Comment: @TimLiberty Or you can add it to only direct descendants of `.sideNav`

Comment: I updated my question. Can you let me know if li inside ul will also need to be display block? because i want to show them inline-block

Comment: @TimLiberty Now they are working as is in my browser, they are not wrapping.

Comment: are li items `I dont want hack` not wrapping?

Comment: @TimLiberty No, they are wrapping. But what is the concern if they are wrapping? Can't you assign them a specific class and only assign display-block to that class?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39738/ is my updated jsfiddle I want to show all lis in single line. How do you suggest to do it?

Comment: @TimLiberty I have updated with a demo in my answer.

Comment: This is what I see https://gyazo.com/ca003bc6f9fd123f4b33d7aadaec0b49 I want `I don't want hack` to shown on the same line. but in your example it lists one word after another on separate lines.

Comment: @TimLiberty Your url is not reachable from my network, Can you add a pic of how you want it to be seen?

Comment: @TimLiberty check the updates once more. I thought you want to wrap, but instead you didn't wanted it to wrap, so just add `white-space: nowrap;`.